# Unordered List css for ie8 - don't want white space

Tags: css

I have an Unordered List in a Div.  The html looks like this:

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="oga-list">
<li>
<a href="#">Test 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Test 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Test 3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.item-list ul.oga-list {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox (the browsers that almost everyone I know uses), it looks fine and the way I want it.  In Internet Explorer 8 (the browsers that the corporate zombies use) there is a white space on the left within the div, therefore the margin and padding is not working.

What can I do?

Comment: Try removing all line breaks from the source, so that you end up with something like this:

`<ul><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul>`

Lists are whitespace-sensitive in IE.

Comment: Try this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/

Comment: I don't see any additional whitespace in IE9 in IE8 mode, but you can try setting the margins and paddings of the `li` elements to 0.